# ng-repeat not updating after search

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I've got an Ionic app in development, and I'm having an unusual error occur. I have a main "jobs" template which the current user will see all of their jobs that have been assigned to them:

```
<ion-view cache-view="false" ng-controller="JobsCtrl">
    <ion-content>
        <ion-list>
            <ion-item ng-repeat="job in jobs" class="item-icon-right item-text-wrap">
                <a href="#" style="text-decoration:none; color: #444;" ng-click="loadJob(job.JobId)">
                  {{job.JobId}} - {{job.Surname}} - {{job.Suburb}} - {{job.JobType}}<i class="icon ion-chevron-right icon-accessory"></i>
               </a>
            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

This view is populated, like so:

```
$http.get(ApiEndpoint.url + '/GetJobs').then(function (resp) {
    $scope.jobs = resp.data;
        $ionicLoading.hide();
 }, function (err) {
            //console.error('ERR', err);
            // err.status will contain the status code
});
```

There is a search box at the top of the template, which when fired, simply GETs a new list of jobs with a search string as the parameter:

```
var searchText = $scope.data.SearchText;
$ionicLoading.show({
    template: '<p>Searching...</p><ion-spinner></ion-spinner>'
});
$http.get(ApiEndpoint.url + '/GetJobs/' + encodeURIComponent(searchText)).then(function (resp) {
    $timeout(function () {
        $scope.jobs = resp.data;
    });
    $ionicLoading.hide();
}, function (err) {
    $ionicLoading.hide();
    //console.error('ERR', err);
    // err.status will contain the status code
});
```

What is happening though, is that the ion-list is not updating when $scope.jobs is assigned the new data. I know for a fact that the GET was successful (via a packet sniffer). I've done a lot of searching around for the answer (hence the $timeout call) - I've also tried applying $scope.$apply(); directly after the $scope.jobs = resp.data; as some sites have suggested, without luck. Any ideas on how I can get it to reload the ng-repeat properly?

Comment: Maybe you could use $watch, then use your get function in there. Let it update the model of the collection.

Comment: Sorry if this is a silly question (still relatively new to Angular/Ionic), however is that going to work if the user has to click a "search" button? Will $watch know when to fire?

Comment: Can you paste the output of `resp.data` ?

Comment: Sure thing, here is the initial /GetJobs/

`[
  {
    "JobId": "1717182",
 "Surname": "TEST SURNAME",
    "Suburb": "TEST SUBURB",
    "JobType": "Field Call"
  },
  {
    "JobId": "1717374",
 "Surname": "TEST SURNAME",
    "Suburb": "TEST SUBURB",
    "JobType": "Process Service"
  },
   {
    "JobId": "1716856",
 "Surname": "TEST SURNAME",
    "Suburb": "TEST SUBURB",
    "JobType": "Process Service"
  }
]`

Comment: Havent actually tried this, but I dont see why not.

Comment: Can you include a small piece of the search input?

Comment: After mucking around a little, and removing the timeout and adding `$scope.$apply();` directly after the `$scope.jobs = resp.data;`, i'm getting this error:

ionic.bundle.js:25642 Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest

Comment: @alphapilgrim Sure thing, I am using the string 1716 (which using my test data above, should only return 1 job), 
the URL looks like this: http://localhost:56909/api/fs/GetJobs/1716, and the result is: 

[
  {
    "JobId": "1716856",
    "Surname": "TEST SURNAME",
    "Suburb": "TEST SUBURB",
    "JobType": "Process Service"
  }
] (checked via the packet sniffer)

Answer (score 0):

Try this variation, might I also suggest not using the $scope reference. Include the $scope reference, but use 'this' instead of $scope. Will update code with when search input area is included if needed.

Example controller:

```
function ExampleCtrl ($scope) {

    var vm = this;

   //I think this should formatted differently.
   var searchText = $scope.data.SearchText;
   //Maybe like this.
   vm.data = {};
   //then vm.data.SearchText will be included from the view model. just make sure to include on html like so, jobs.data.SearchText

   $ionicLoading.show({
        template: '<p>Searching...</p><ion-spinner></ion-spinner>'
    });
    $http.get(ApiEndpoint.url + '/GetJobs/' + encodeURIComponent(searchText)).then(function (resp) {
    $timeout(function () {
        vm.jobs = resp.data;
    });
       $ionicLoading.hide();
    }, function (err) {
        $ionicLoading.hide();
        //console.error('ERR', err);
        // err.status will contain the status code
    });

ExampleCtrl.$inject = ['$scope'];

angular
   .module('example')
   .controller('ExampleCtrl', ExampleCtrl);


 <ion-view cache-view="false" ng-controller="JobsCtrl as jobs">
  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
        <ion-item ng-repeat="job in jobs.jobs" class="item-icon-right item-text-wrap">
            <a href="#" style="text-decoration:none; color: #444;" ng-click="loadJob(job.JobId)">
              {{job.JobId}} - {{job.Surname}} - {{job.Suburb}} - {{job.JobType}}<i class="icon ion-chevron-right icon-accessory"></i>
           </a>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Update for search input:

```
<ion-header-bar style="background-color: transparent; " class="item-input-inset">
<form ng-submit="jobs.submitSearch()">
    <label class="item-input-wrapper"> <i class="icon ion-search placeholder-icon"></i>
        <input type="search" placeholder="Search" ng-model="jobs.data.SearchText"> </label>
</form>
```

Comment: This is the search form - I will have a crack at the above code changes too and see `<ion-header-bar style="background-color: transparent; " class="item-input-inset">
    <form ng-submit="submitSearch()">
        <label class="item-input-wrapper">
            <i class="icon ion-search placeholder-icon"></i>
            <input type="search" placeholder="Search" ng-model="data.SearchText">
        </label>
    </form>
</ion-header-bar>`

Comment: Just at first glance, it seems as though the input is out of scope. I'll update. If you're reusing the search input throughout the app, the above might not work.